# Change class when page is active

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

How can I set a .html page active when I change pages?
This is needed to change the active tab in my nav bar.
I should add the class `.current_page_item` to the active li of the nav.

I've searched a bit around, but I couldn't find a fitting answer.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can find the files via this link
---> http://matt-productions.be/berto/index.html

I haven't tried much, because I don't know how to start doing it

Comment: You need to read the current document URL using JavaScript, iterate the tab items and find the item referencing the URL of the current document, then add the class to it. That's a good starting point for you, try it yourself and update this post with your progress.

Comment: As far as I can see the nav is static, no ajax requests. Why not simply modify the other HTML files and move the class to the right `<li/>`?

Comment: That's the issue.
I'm working with a dynamic template and if I want to add an editable field to my li class, it selects the whole <li>.
So that means that the purpose of my template is useless

Comment: I'm nearly finished, but I have 1 final issue.
How can I create an array of all my <li> tags and add the required class to the right index of that array?

Comment: Could you explaine exactly what you mean by 'required class to the right index of that array'?

Comment: For example:
If the url ends with index.html the code would look like this
"arrayWithLi[0].addclass("active")
or
"arrayWithLi[3].addclass("active") (this might be the contact page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you need with jquery

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

       var links = $('nav').children();
       $.each(links, function(key, value){
          if(value.href == document.URL){
           $(this).addClass('current_page_item');
          }
       });
   </script>
    <nav>
        <a href="/link1">link-1</a>
        <a href="/link2">link-2</a>
        <a href="/link3">link-3</a>
        <a href="/link4">link-4</a>
        <a href="index.html">link-5</a>
    </nav>
```

Link 5 will get the active class because its the same as the current url

---

### The Result

```
<nav>
    <a href="/link1">link-1</a>
    <a href="/link2">link-2</a>
    <a href="/link3">link-3</a>
    <a href="/link4">link-4</a>
    <a class="current_page_item" href="index.html">link-5</a>
</nav>
```

---

Comment: Great!
I just fixed the problem in an unholy way, but this solution is way better. I might change it later
Thanks!